# reassembly of tcp packet

Tags: c++, tcp, packet

I'm parsing a file with lots of tcp packets which i need to parse. The problem is that they get segmented and i can't find any indication when and where they do so. No flags or anything else indicates, that the middle of current packet may contain the beginning of the next one. The protocol above tcp is FIX(used in online trading) but i'd like for my code to be able to work with any protocols(or at least understand which is protocol is it).
I'm writing code in C++ and can't use any additional libraries.
So, how do i figure out what is the protocol above tcp and where it gets segmented ?

Comment: To reassemble TCP streams, first you must learn how to reassemble IP fragments.  See RFC 815.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. How was this data captured?

Comment: @Alnitak I doubt he is capturing raw data here. RFC 815 is what happens inside a network stack, not outside on the user level.

Comment: @H.Guijt unless you're reading pcap files...   (and yeah, it's unclear what the source of this files is)

Comment: @Alnitak He might also be looking at electrical signals on his oscilloscope, but lacking further information I think it is reasonable to assume the normal user-level API...

Comment: I do have a pcap file. But i don't see ip fragmentation.

Comment: @ВиталикБушаев if the pcap is recorded between two devices on the same LAN, you probably won't.  If there's any WAN links involved it becomes much more likely.   FWIW, TCP stream reassembly isn't very easy - you also potentially need to keep track of the TCP state machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. TCP/IP is conceptually a stream, not a sequence of messages (the fact that it is ultimately implemented as a sequence of packets is irrelevant). When you write a sequence of bytes to a TCP/IP stream, that sequence is added to the stream; it is not treated as a message which should maintain its own identity. No notion of message begin/end is transmitted along with the stream, unless you do so yourself in your own protocol.

If you find this hard to believe, consider how it works for files: if you write a sequence of bytes to a file, that sequence does not somehow become a record that you can later identify and retrieve. If you want that kind of structure you have to add it yourself. The same is true for TCP/IP.

The transport packets used to implement TCP/IP have no relation to the data blocks you specify with your API calls; they are merely a way to implement the TCP/IP stream. For some use cases there may appear to be a mapping, but this is accidental.

The only way to split a TCP/IP stream back into separate messages is by using knowledge of the protocol running on top of TCP/IP. In your case this is FIX. I assume you know how that works; you can use that knowledge to correctly split the FIX data back into its original messages. A generic TCP/IP message splitter cannot be made.

Comment: s/packets/message/g, please - packets are what go over the wire in layer 2 and layer 3 protocols : protocol messages -> TCP stream -> TCP segments -> IP packets -> Ethernet packets

Comment: I've changed packet to message where appropriate, but since the original question already asked about packets I'm not certain it has become more clear as a result.

Answer (score -2):

As I can see your problem is to separate TCP packets. To solve it you can relay on length of payload ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639799/calculate-size-and-start-of-tcp-packet-data-excluding-header)) and checksum. If checksum is correct for data with specified length, than your packet is correct, if no - you need seek in thee previous part for start of the packet or drop this part of data.  At least this approach will help you to find point where dada was segmented.

For more precise answer it will be better to see little part of data.

But main your problem is segmentation of packets. For better performance you should try to exclude this problem (maybe change network card to Intel).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: The segmentation is part of the TCP/IP protocol, and has precisely nothing to do with the brand of network card involved.